# How to exclude package in R from downloading automatically?

Tags: r

I am trying to download the GGMAP package in R. during installation, it also downloads ggplot 2.1.0. I am getting an error, however, that the ggplot version required by ggmap is 2.2.0. How do I force ggplot to be the latest version?

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
Downloading GitHub repo dkahle/ggmap@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/dkahle/ggmap/zipball/master
Installing ggmap
"C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/dixi/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuYriTy/devtools2604499b1ebd/dkahle-ggmap-065fe6a"  \
  --library="C:/Users/dixi/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'ggmap' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : package 'ggplot2' 2.1.0 was found, but >= 2.2.0 is required by 'ggmap'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggmap'
* removing 'C:/Users/dixi/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ggmap'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/dixi/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ggmap'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: From the message you posted here, it looks like ggplot2 2.1.0 is the version already present in your system, rather than anything that ggmap downloads. (The current ggplot2 version is 3.1.1. I doubt you can install 2.1.0 from anywhere without quite a bit of hassle.) Suggest you run `install.packages()` for ggplot2 to get the latest.

Comment: You may also want to update your R version, which appears to be 3.3 (more than 2 years out of date). The latest is already 3.6.

Comment: Thank you! it looks like that is the problem. It works now after I updated my R version.